# Draw koch snowflake using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, turtle-graphics

I am trying to write code for a koch recursion method. I made it this far however I cant seem to figure out how to turn the turtle and get an actual snowflake shape.

Any sort of explanation will be much appreciated, thanks!

```
import java.awt.Color;


public class Triangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        World myWorld = new World(900,900,Color.GREEN);
        Turtle bob = new Turtle(myWorld);
        bob.setDelay(0);
        //drawTriangle(bob, 4, -200,-100,405,-100,100,350.75);

        koch(bob, 3, 12.0);

    }

     public static void koch(Turtle t, int n, double size) {
        if(n==0)
            t.forward(size);
        else
        {
            koch(t, n-1, size);
            t.left(60);
            koch(t, n-1, size);
            t.right(120);
            koch(t, n-1, size);
            t.left(60);
            koch(t, n-1, size);
        }


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to replace:

```
koch(bob, 3, 12.0);
```

with:

```
koch(bob, 3, 12.0);
bob.right(120);
koch(bob, 3, 12.0);
bob.right(120);
koch(bob, 3, 12.0);
```

or the equivalent loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    koch(bob, 3, 12.0);
    bob.right(120);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]